# PHP Array does not add new elements from HTML form

Tags: php, html, arrays, forms

New to PHP and web development. I feel stupid asking this but been browsing for answers for hours and can't find anything. If this has been answered before please link me... Thank you for any help!

Description:
Using HTML form, pass values as an array to PHP array. Works first time, but when I go back to the form and try to add another set of values, it overrides the values at index 0.

What I've Tried:
array_push($log, $_POST["info"]) and $log[] = $_POST["info"]; = same result, index at 0 is overwritten.

**HTML Code**

```
 <?php $date = date('d/m/Y h:i', time());?>
 <form class="contact-form" action="/server.php" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="info[]" placeholder="Full name" required>
        <textarea name="info[]" rows="5" cols ="80" placeholder="Message" required></textarea>
        <input type="hidden" name="info[]" id="date-time" value="<?php echo $date; ?>"> 
        <button type="submit" name="submit">Submit Message</button>      
 </form>
```

**PHP Code**

```
<?php
    $log = array();

    if(isset($_POST["info"])){
      array_push($log, $_POST["info"]);
    }

    var_dump($log);
?>
```

**Current Result**

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(12) "Blunder King"
    [1]=>
    string(28) "Blundering all the day long."
    [2]=>
    string(16) "27/11/2021 02:48"
  }
}
```

When I try to add another value to the $log array, it gets overwritten instead of moving new index.

```
array(1) {
  [0] =>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(12) "Blunder King"
    [1]=>
    string(28) "Blundering all the day long."
    [2]=>
    string(16) "27/11/2021 02:48"
  }, // would expect new array values at index 1. But instead I get these values overwriting index 0 above.
  [1] =>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(12) "Blunder Queen"
    [1]=>
    string(30) "Blundering all the day long."
    [2]=>
    string(16) "27/11/2021 02:51"
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you point to a line in your PHP code you would expect to persist this data between form submissions…?

Comment: I think what you are misunderstanding is that every time you press the Submit button it loads a fresh server.php script. Any of your old data that was there is gone.  Is the HTML code and PHP code in the same file? If so, you can simply pass the previous data in a hidden form element. JavaScript might also help depending on what exactly you are trying to do here.

Comment: @dev_blunder88 Ok, but you still haven’t addressed my comment - what line or lines in your current code do you expect to persist the data you POST between distinct form submissions?

Comment: @kojow7 thanks for the reply. The HTML code and PHP code are in two separate files. But I suspect you are right that it is calling a fresh PHP script everytime. Could you please elaborate a bit more on the hidden from element and how to use that to not reset the php script? Do you mean just adding type="hidden" to the form element?

Comment: @esqew 
Forgive me I don't really understand the question. And again fairly new to all the web development stuff. Doesn't the $_POST variable just get updated with the new input and is submitted to the PHP script everytime on submit? Otherise, if you mean persistent data, I am writing it to a JSON file, which is working - currently I have not develop code to read it back as I'm still trying to figure out how to populate array.

Comment: Each time you click submit button, server.php is re-run. Therefore, $log is re-generated as a new variable and does not retain the original value. PHP doesn't know to previous $log

Comment: I would recommend you to store the array in a SESSION variable, so that the previous submitted data will persist.

Comment: I disagree with Ken Lee's suggestion here. While it could work, a SESSION variable could cause all sorts of issues depending on what you are doing. For example, a SESSION variable could time out after some time and you would lose all of your data.

Comment: @dev_blunder88 Any time you call a PHP script it will always be a fresh call to the script. If you can explain the purpose of your app it would help us provide you with a better solution. Is this a homework assignment or does it have a specific goal you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: @dev_blunder88 A couple of solutions here: OPTION 1: Use a datastore (such as a database or json file). When your PHP script is called, read the existing data from the file into an array, append the new data to the array, save the new data out. OPTION 2: Place all the HTML code in your server.php script. If you have data in your $_POST (add it to the hidden HTML element) and append to it each time.

Comment: Thank you for the replies everyone. @kojow7 Yes it is for an assignment, just to demonstrate basic Web Server Application using HTML/CSS/Javscript & PHP. I did go down the path of using the JSON file for persistent data. After every submit I decode the JSON file if it existed, add the values to the array, then add the form values.

Comment: With the Session variables, not sure about timeout, the goal with the PHP was to develop a trailing message board like this one here! Where a user would add a comment, and it would appear on the page. Then another person would add another comment and it would appear under the latest message.

Comment: @dev_blunder88 did you get it working the way you wanted with using the JSON file?

Answer (score -2):

Simply slightly change your code to use SESSION:

```
<?php  session_start();
$date = date('d/m/Y h:i', time());?>

<form class="contact-form" action="server.php" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="info[]" placeholder="Full name" required>
        <textarea name="info[]" rows="5" cols ="80" placeholder="Message" required></textarea>
        <input type="hidden" name="info[]" id="date-time" value="<?php echo $date; ?>"> 
        <button type="submit" name="submit">Submit Message</button>      
 </form>
```

For server.php

```
<?php session_start();
    
    if ( ! isset($_SESSION["log"])){
       $_SESSION["log"] = array();
}

    if(isset($_POST["info"])){
         array_push($_SESSION["log"], $_POST["info"]);
    }

    var_dump($_SESSION["log"]);
?>
```

Or simply merge the two together and run it and you will see the result in a single php:

```
<?php 
session_start();
?>

<?php $date = date('d/m/Y h:i', time());?>
 <form class="contact-form" action="#" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="info[]" placeholder="Full name" required>
        <textarea name="info[]" rows="5" cols ="80" placeholder="Message" required></textarea>
        <input type="hidden" name="info[]" id="date-time" value="<?php echo $date; ?>"> 
        <button type="submit" name="submit">Submit Message</button>      
 </form>


 <?php
    
    if ( ! isset($_SESSION["log"])){
      $_SESSION["log"] = array();
    }

    if(isset($_POST["info"])){
      array_push($_SESSION["log"], $_POST["info"]);
    }

    var_dump($_SESSION["log"]);
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for this @Ken Lee, I'm going to give this a whirl later on the week, submission was due 12am 28/11/21, and we're learning Cloud development tomorrow (doing a Masters in Software Dev). But I def need to try it out.